# Loading Images in to TableViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

I am loading images from a RESTApi into a Netflix like ScrollView.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ccell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionCell
    cell.imageView.image = nil
    cell.labelText.text = self.data[indexPath.row].kategorie
    cell.model = self.data[indexPath.row].model!
    cell.progressHud.startAnimating()
    let url = self.data[indexPath.row].thumbnail_image_name

    if let imageFromCache = imageCache.object(forKey: url as AnyObject) as? UIImage{
        cell.imageView.image = imageFromCache
    }else{
    Download.fetchPhoto(id: 1, url: self.data[indexPath.row].thumbnail_image_name) { (image) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            cell.imageView.image = image
            cell.progressHud.stopAnimating()
        }
        self.imageCache.setObject(image, forKey:url as AnyObject)
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

I am caching the images in a ImageCache. So far so good. The Problem is, that every time I open the TableviewController the Downloading task starts all over again. what would be the best practice to save the images once they have been downloaded, even after the presenting vc has been closed.

Save them to the device?
while dismissing, send the cache back to the presenting vc?

Maybe you have some ideas.

Thank you!

Comment: This will be a wild guess but I think `imageCache` is a variable on your `TableViewController` so whenever you open the `TableViewController` it also resets. What you need to do is to store `imageCache` variable in a singleton shared instance and then use it.

Answer (score 0):

Because your download method is called in `cellForRow` this will fetch every time a new cell is going to be dequeued.

I would suggest doing the download in `viewDidLoad()` and save the downloaded images into an array which your cell can reference. When the download is finished you can tell your collection view to reload its data.

If you do not want to download the images every time you see the screen you will need to persist the downloaded image data and then you can access that instead of calling download in `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: I have a LaunchViewController that is handling some download tasks.
It might actually be better to let the user wait during the launch, than to let them wait every time displaying the scrollView. I will add the image download task to that controller... thanks

Comment: @Aknitt that's not a very user-friendly experience, to wait for the app to download images each time the app starts.
Why not use Kingfisher to download images, and it is doing that on a background thread, and you can show a loading indicator or a placeholder image while the image is being downloaded. Kingfisher is handling it himself the imageCache, so the next time you won't have to download again the same image. Also, Kingfisher is highly modifiable. Just take a look at it [here](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher)